# Symfony3—Test Service with authentification

Tags: unit-testing, symfony

I am trying to test a Service which preprocessed a form and finally saves it. Within the creating of that form:

```
$this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```

is called to get currently logged in user as a default value for a field.

Right now I am having this (extending `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase`):

```
private $pages;
private $formFactory;

protected function setUp()
{
  self::bootKernel();

  $client = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('test.client');
  $client->setServerParameters([
    'HTTP_HOST'                   => 'ajax.localhost.dev:10190',
    'CONTENT_TYPE'              => 'application/json',
    'HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'HTTP_USER_AGENT'         => 'Symfony/2.0',
    'PHP_AUTH_USER'             => 'root',
    'PHP_AUTH_PW'               => 'root@localhost.dev'
  ]);

  $this->pages = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('app.pages');
  $this->formFactory = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('form.factory');
}

public function testNewPage() {
  $page = new Page();
  //shortened
  $form = $this->formFactory->create(PageType::class, $page);
}
```

But that gives me the error:

```
Call to a member function getUser() on null
```

What shows that there is no security token.

How can I come over that?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the comments of @LBA I tried that code, with no luck:

```
$session = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('session');
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken('root', 'root', 'main', ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ROOT']);
$session->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
$session->save();
```

The part with setting a Cookie as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/simulating_authentication.html) is missing, since the `$kernel` has no method `getCookieJar()`

Comment: are you sure you have a logged-in user after setUp?

Comment: @LBA please see the updated code. I was wrong by passing the options array to `bootKernel()`. But that is not working, too.

Comment: still I don't get how your user should be logged in - how is login done in your application? you are not sending user name and password with each request as a serverparameter/header, aren't you?

Comment: @LBA the code above is copied from some functional tests, where I do »real« requests, using the client. But this time I would love to just test the service, but with a logged in user. I do not know how to fake a logged in user this way.

Comment: again, how is authentication done in your app? and please check this out: http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/simulating_authentication.html or even better this one: http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/http_authentication.html

Comment: @LBA I think I have got your Point now! In the other functional tests I am following the approach described in the second link you have posted, what is working as it should, because everything is done using `$client->request(…)`, so the credentials are transfered with that. This time I would like to not use the `$client` and just test the classes directly, if that is possible. In other words: set the security token directly.

Comment: then check first link

Comment: @LBA please see my update…

Answer (score 1):

I could finally make it work like so:

```
protected function setUp()
{
  self::bootKernel();

  $root = new User();
  $root->setUsername('root');
  $root->setPassword('root');
  $root->setEmail('root@localhost.dev');

  $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($root, null, 'main', ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ROOT']);

  self::$kernel->getContainer()
    ->get('security.token_storage')
    ->setToken($token);

  $this->pages = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('app.pages');
  $this->formFactory = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('form.factory');
}
```

**BUT** **BUT** **BUT** Even if it is possible to solve that problem, the real issue in this case is, to have that `$this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();` call with the Form, since this breaks the form in a test case. The pattern to prevent such a thing from happening is dependency injection, what I have missed to apply on the form type.

So the better solution would be (in the Form extending AbstractType):

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
  $this->setDefined(['user]);
}
```

And finally create the form like so (in Controller **or** TestCase)

Within a UnitTest:

```
$user = new User();
```

and in the controller:

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

$form = $this->formFactory->create(TheFormType::class, 
  <some data object>, 
  ['user' => $user]);
```

Comment: glad you got it